# Why do we need pointer to member operator in C

Tags: c

I ask this in relation to C as, in many senses, it's a precursor to C++.

Let's suppose that the pointer to member operator `->` was replaced with `.`. Are there any instances when this would introduce ambiguity?

If not then why was an extra operator introduced? For such a terse language it seems an unnecessary extravagance.

Comment: I wouldn't describe C as terse...

Comment: I learnt 32 keyword C. Cf. VB.

Comment: I think the spirit of C is to be explicit to the point that no boring detail is left implied, including automatic dereferencing for member access. Since there's a very important distinction in C between pointer variables and object variables, it makes sense to keep the syntax distinct.

Answer (score 2):

`ptr->member` is just a simpler way to write `(*ptr).member`